# Редирект в зависимости от текущего местоположения

Tags: php

Есть два типа страниц: loginpage и страницы всего остального сайта.
Логин производится по сессиям. В переменную `$_SESSION['logged_user']` записываю объект пользователя.
В скрипте "выхода из сайта" указываю `unset($_SESSION['logged_user'])`.
Всё ли правильно тут делаю?

Конкретно по вопросу, то хочется написать такое условие:

```
Если текущая страница loginpage, то
  Если создана переменная $_SESSION['logged_user'], то
    редирект на mainpage
Иначе
  Если не создана переменная $_SESSION['logged_user'], то
    редирект на loginpage
```

Как я понимаю, редирект делается так: `header('Location: /client/mainpage');`
А как сделать проверки по адресу, не знаю.

**UPD:**

Вроде разобрался с откуда доставать адреса, вот, что получилось:

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/client/login/index.php') {
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
        header('Location: /client/mainpage');
        exit();
    }
} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
        header('Location: /client/login');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Всё ли правильно написал?
Правда хочется, чтобы в этой строчке `header('Location: /client/mainpage');` была не mainpage, а страница, с которой перешел пользователь. То есть обратно назад его отсылало. То есть типа, если он был на какой-нибудь /blogpage, а затем в адресной строке ввел /loginpage, сработал бы скрипт и его бы отослало обратно, а не на /mainpage. Как такое сделать?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Не забудьте проверить, что переход на страницу авотризации был именно с Вашего сайта.

Comment: @Андрей, ага, спасибо.